# Safari multiple hashtags

Tags: jquery, url, safari

I recently tested my site on Safari and for some odd reason it only reads the first hashtag in the url

http://www.mangamanga.com/mangaReader.php#mangaNo=3%23chapterNo=8%23pageNo=1

while in all the other browsers it looks like this

http://www.mangamanga.com/mangaReader.php#mangaNo=3#chapterNo=8#pageNo=1

could someone please explain why this is happening.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need multiple hash tags?

Comment: Is this the actual URL that is sent to the server or is it just the browsers that display it like this?

Comment: the first is how the browser is displaying it and the second is how it is being sent over the server

Comment: @Gumbo: The part after the # is never sent to the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash (#) is a reserved character in URLs. Any characters following the hash are the fragment portion of a URL. So Safari is escaping the extra illegal hashes to %23.

http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html

Answer (score 2):

A plain `#` is actually not allowed in the [*fragment* component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5):

```
fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
```

Where *pchar* is equivalent to this expansion:

```
pchar       = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG / "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "=" / ":" / "@"
```

No plain `#` there. So Safari’s behavior would be the expected behavior.

But maybe the other browsers are just displaying the `%23` as `#` for readability.

Answer (score 0):

%23 is how # symbols are escaped.  Apparently Safari feels like doing this, where other browsers don't.  It seems to load the same page in any case.

Here's a list of escape codes:
http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html

Answer (score 0):

What most people have been saying is true; Safari does see it as an illegal character (the second hash) but other modern browsers (IE/Chrome) are fine with them.

Gumbo stated that the other browsers are just displaying the second hash as # but it's really %23. This is incorrect as far as I can tell, because using a `document.location.hash.split('#')` will give you the following array:

```
[0] - http://www.mangamanga.com/mangaReader.php#mangaNo=3
[1] - chapterNo=8
[2] - pageNo=1
```